# Do Bernoulli polynomials know about face vectors?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polyhedra, polytopes, bernoulli-numbers

This question is grounded firmly in numerology.  It originates in an observation about some Bernoulli polynomials and the regular icosahedron.  Let $F_{k+1}(n)=\sum_{i=1}^n i^k$ be the sum of the first $n$ $k$th powers of positive integers.  We know that $F_k$ is a polynomial of degree $k$ that is related to Bernoulli polynomials via an affine-linear substitution for $n$.  The observation here concerns $F_5$ and $F_7$.  Specifically, we see
$$60F_5(n)=12n^5+30n^4+20n^3-2n$$
and
$$168F_7(n)=24n^7+84n^6+84n^5-28n^3+4n.$$
Notice that the coefficients of $60F_5$ coincide with the face vector of a regular icosahedron (20 triangles, 30 edges, 12 vertices).  Also, the coefficients of $168F_7$ nearly coincide with the face vector of a surface related to the Klein quartic.  This is a "regular" triangulation of a surface of genus 3 that has 24 vertices, 84 edges, and 56 triangles.  Notice that the sum of the coefficients of $168F_7$ on the terms of degrees 5 and 3 is 56.
The numbers 60 and 168 are significant because they are the orders of a couple of groups that act on these polyhedra.

Is this a coincidence?  Are there similar phenomena relating higher-degree Bernoulli polynomials to regular triangulations of other surfaces?  Should I lay off the moonshine?

Comment: "a surface related to the Klein quartic", can you elaborate? From Wikipedia: "Klein quartic forms part of a "trinity" in the sense of Vladimir Arnold, which can also be described as a McKay correspondence. In this collection, the [...] groups PSL(2,5), PSL(2,7), and PSL(2,11) (orders 60, 168, 660) are analogous, corresponding to icosahedral symmetry (genus 0), the symmetries of the Klein quartic (genus 3), and the buckyball surface (genus 70).[12] These are further connected to many other exceptional phenomena, which is elaborated at "trinities"." so maybe $660F_{11}$ will be relevant?

Comment: Maybe `p=3` and `p=23` would also be interesting to consider ?

Answer (score 4):

Following up on i9Fn's suggestion, there does seem to be at least one more case along these lines: $$660F_{11}(n) = 60n^{11} + 330n^{10} + 550n^9 - 660n^7 + 660n^5 - 330n^3 + 50n.$$
This might be related to a genus 70 Riemann surface with 11 embedded buckyballs; see Martin & Singerman [From biplanes to the Klein quartic and the Buckyball](http://www.neverendingbooks.org/DATA/biplanesingerman.pdf).  Each buckyball/ buckminsterfullerene has 60 vertices, 90 edges, and 32 faces.  The number 660 arises as both the order of $PSL(2,11)$ and the count of particular triangles.

Comment: There is a "regular" triangulation of a genus 26 surface related to the group PSL(2,11).  This has 60 vertices, 330 edges, and 220 triangles.  It is described in this article by Ioannis Ivrissimtzis, David Singerman, and James Strudwick:  https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.08568.  Seeing $660F_{11}$ here, one again notices some coincidences in the coefficients.  Here, one must add the coefficients of the terms of degree 9, 7, 5, and 3 to get the number 220 of triangles.

Comment: Another observation:  The coefficients -2, 4, and 50 are the negatives of the respective Euler characteristics of these surfaces which seem to correspond to $F_5$, $F_7$ and $F_{11}$.

Comment: It would be even crazier if all of this connected to the Ramanujan partition congruences which hold (in the most thorough sense) only modulo 5, 7, and 11.

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly, the polynomials are

```
sage: 12*(bernoulli_polynomial(x,5)-bernoulli(5))                               
12*x^5 - 30*x^4 + 20*x^3 - 2*x
sage: 24*(bernoulli_polynomial(x,7)-bernoulli(7))                               
24*x^7 - 84*x^6 + 84*x^5 - 28*x^3 + 4*x
sage: 60*(bernoulli_polynomial(x,11)-bernoulli(11))                             
60*x^11 - 330*x^10 + 550*x^9 - 660*x^7 + 660*x^5 - 330*x^3 + 50*x
```

where the scaling factors are the cardinalities of the groups $A_4$, $S_4$, $A_5$.

Comment: And the odd Bernoulli numbers vanish, so one can remove them from the formula.